# How to work around Safari 10.1 error "Failed to send WebSocket frame"?

Tags: javascript, websocket, safari, webkit

It seems that the WebSocket API in Safari 10.1 has a maximum amount of binary data that it can buffer and then the next message sent gets the error "WebSocket connection to ... failed: Failed to send WebSocket frame."

Safari then closes the connection with code 1006 (CLOSE_ABNORMAL).

WebSockets are [supposed to report the `bufferedAmount`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#dom-websocket-bufferedamount) - but Safari always reports `0` until *after* the error occurs and the connection is closed.

I tried just doing 100ms a setTimeout between each message, and that seems to work in the case of small chunks of data, but it seems brittle and large chunks still get errors when I send my closing JSON message, even with a longer delay.

You can [see the bug in action here](https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/) - the "Play Sample" buttons work in Safari 10.03 but error in 10.1. ([Code that handles the WebSocket connection.](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/v0.32.3/speech-to-text/recognize-stream.js))

Any ideas on how to work around this? Or what the limit even is? I know that Safari is Open Source, but I'm not sure where to look.

Update: here's a simpler example:

```
// this fails in Safari 10.1 but works in 10.03 (and other browsers)
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

ws.onerror = function(evt) {
  // Not sure why, but error events seem to have no useful information
  // The console, however, will have the following error:
  // WebSocket connection to 'wss://echo.websocket.org/' failed: Failed to send WebSocket frame.
  console.log("WebSocket error - see console for message");
}
ws.onclose = function(evt) {
  console.log(`WebSocket closed with code: ${evt.code}, reason: ${evt.reason}`);
}

ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('sending first binary message');
  ws.send(new Uint8Array(23085));
  console.log('bufferedAmount is ' + ws.bufferedAmount);

  // this gets the error
  console.log('sending second binary message');
  ws.send(new Uint8Array(23085));
  console.log('bufferedAmount is ' + ws.bufferedAmount);

  console.log('sending third binary message');
  ws.send(new Uint8Array(23085));
  console.log('bufferedAmount is ' + ws.bufferedAmount);

  ws.close();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yta2mjuf/2/

The second message gets an error closes the connection, and after the third message, `bufferedAmount` is 23093.

Comment: we are experiencing the same issue. The threshold for us seems to be a buffer of UInt8Array(23085); anything larger, and we see the same error.
(We too see the bufferedAmount always reporting 0). Sorry can't be more help at the moment - don't know if this is a Safari bug or some new security thing.

Comment: I filed a bug on WebKit here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170463

Comment: the same on our side, waiting for the fix...

Comment: Status seems to say this regression is fixed, but I'm still experiencing this /:

Comment: If you download the preview for the next release of macOS, it's fixed there. I think the final release will go out to everyone in a month or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your real world link on Safari 10.1.2 and did not see the problem. Seems it has been fixed.